# запуск tomcat через ант

Tags: tomcat, ant

Проходил старый гайд по спрингу [Spring Step by step](http://docs.spring.io/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/part1.html)

Делал все чисто как написано, но вот возникла одна проблема: при попытке запуска таска Ant на запуск Tomcat выкидывает ошибку Connection refused. По англоязычным топам пробежался, но подходящего решения так и не нашел.

```
<path id="catalina-ant-classpath">
    <!-- We need the Catalina jars for Tomcat -->
    <!--  * for other app servers - check the docs -->
    <fileset dir="${appserver.lib}">
        <include name="catalina-ant.jar"/>
    </fileset>
</path>

<taskdef name="install" classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.InstallTask">
    <classpath refid="catalina-ant-classpath"/>
</taskdef>
<taskdef name="reload" classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.ReloadTask">
    <classpath refid="catalina-ant-classpath"/>
</taskdef>
<taskdef name="list" classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.ListTask">
    <classpath refid="catalina-ant-classpath"/>
</taskdef>
<taskdef name="start" classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.StartTask">
    <classpath refid="catalina-ant-classpath"/>
</taskdef>
<taskdef name="stop" classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.StopTask">
    <classpath refid="catalina-ant-classpath"/>
</taskdef>

<target name="install" description="Install application in Tomcat">
    <install url="${tomcat.manager.url}"
             username="${tomcat.manager.username}"
             password="${tomcat.manager.password}"
             path="/${name}"
             war="${name}"/>
</target>

<target name="reload" description="Reload application in Tomcat">
    <reload url="${tomcat.manager.url}"
             username="${tomcat.manager.username}"
             password="${tomcat.manager.password}"
             path="/${name}"/>
</target>

<target name="start" description="Start Tomcat application">
    <start url="${tomcat.manager.url}"
             username="${tomcat.manager.username}"
             password="${tomcat.manager.password}"
             path="/${name}"/>
</target>

<target name="stop" description="Stop Tomcat application">
    <stop url="${tomcat.manager.url}"
             username="${tomcat.manager.username}"
             password="${tomcat.manager.password}"
             path="/${name}"/>
</target>

<target name="list" description="List Tomcat applications">
    <list url="${tomcat.manager.url}"
             username="${tomcat.manager.username}"
             password="${tomcat.manager.password}"/>
</target>
```

Ошибка:

```
Buildfile: C:\JavaProjects\springapp\build.xml 

list: 

BUILD FAILED 
F:\Java Programs\Ant project folder\springapp\build.xml:123: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect 
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) 
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:333) 
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:195) 
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:182) 
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366) 
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529) 
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:478)....
```

Может сталкивался кто. Посоветуйте как исправить. Заранее спасибо

Comment: Что в этой строке build.xml:123?

Comment: @VladislavPyatkov,   в той строке path="/${name}", где name это property со значением springapp. Думал, что не коннектит по причине установки tomcat на системном диске (тип прав недостаточно), но перенос на другой диск дает тот же результат.

Comment: Думаю причина в том что апсервер не стартует, а уже потом к нему невозможно присоединиться.
Попробуйте руками его запустить, через %CATALINA_HOME%\bin\startup